# Select root node by text and add child

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a child node to a root node.

The root node's text is "Hello".

How can I go about adding "hi" as a child node, to the root node, "Hello"

I tried this

```
databaseInfoTreeView.SelectedNode = "Hello";
databaseInfoTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("Hi");
```

But I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'

On this line `databaseInfoTreeView.SelectedNode = "Hello";`

Why doesn't it work, and how do I do this correctly?

[image]

Comment: The string `"hello"` is not the `TreeNode` object. You want to find the `TreeNode` that has the string `"hello"` as its `Text` property.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The TreeNode is called databaseInfoTreeView. I added a picture of what the treeView looks like. I think I just don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select tree nodes using a text. You need to get a reference for the "Hello" node some other way. You could:

1) Get the reference when you create the node and then add a child:

```
var root = databaseInfoTreeView.Nodes.Add("Hello");
root.Nodes.Add("Hi");

// Then if you want you can even set it as the current selected node
databaseInfoTreeView.SelectedNode = root;
```

2) Get the reference directly from the node index:

```
var root = databaseInfoTreeView.Nodes[0];
root.Nodes.Add("Hi");
```

3) Manually select the node on the treeview control, on you user interface and then add a node programatically:

```
if (databaseInfoTreeView.SelectedNode != null)
    databaseInfoTreeView.Nodes.Add("Hi");
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Oo. That actually helps a lot! Thanks mate

Comment: @ILovephp123 If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer...

Comment: This issue with this, is that the nodes I'm adding as root, are going to be dynamically given. So I don't know what to name the variable. I would use an array but that's not helpful. Number 3 works great tho. THanks